# Help me find a less tedious way to prove this theorem about inequalities

Tags: calculus, inequality

I'm currently working through Spivak's Calculus and am currently in Chapter 1. So far, the book has covered commutativity, associativity, existence of an inverse and existence of an identity for addition and multiplication. The book has also covered the distributive law and the three inequality laws, that is every number is either positive, negative or zero as well as closure under addition and multiplication.

The problem is to prove that if $ x<y$ then $x^n<y^n$ for all odd $n$. At this point, I imagine I'm only allowed to use any of the given properties, or anything I can prove.

I have a proof, but it's a bunch of case analyses and induction. Here it is:

Either $x\in P$ and $y \in P$ or $-x \in P$ and $y \in P$ or $-x \in P$ and $-y \in P$ or $x \in O$ and $y \in P$ or $-x \in P$ and $y \in O$.

If $x \in P$ and $y \in P$ then trivially, $x^n<y^n$ (I proved this already.)

If $-x \in P$ and $y \in P$ then either $x^2 < y^2$ or $y^2<x^2$.

If $x^2<y^2$, then assume $x^n<y^n$ for some odd $n$ it follows that $x^{n+2}<y^{n+2}$ and $x^n < y^n$ for all odd $n$.

If $y^2<x^2$, then it's true $y^{2n}<x^{2n}$ for all $n$. It follows that $y^{2n}x<x^{2n}y$ and $x^{2n-1}<y^{2n-1}$ (since $x$ is negative) and therefore $x^n < y^n$ for all odd $n$.

The rest of my proof is just a bunch more of this for the rest of the cases. I don't think there's anything wrong with my proof per se, but can anyone suggest a more elegant approach? This is really super tedious.

Comment: If $x$ is negative and $y$ positive, we're done. So ignore that case. If they're both negative, flip signs and prove the reverse inequality. So we've reduced to when they're both positive. Then if you know that $x<y$, multiply by $x$ to get $x^2<xy<y^2$, which completes a proof via induction. Notice we used the oddness in the opposite signs case.